# On hover, hide image show div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this will require Jquery, but what I'm trying to achieve is to list a set of images (let's use one image for example) that will hide when hovered over and will show a div with a background image and text.

How would one go about achieving this effect?

I have this so far but the image keeps flickering: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/126/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning and z-indexes. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PPpnT/)

Alternatively, use the opacity rule. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PPpnT/1/)

In your case, I would suggest using the opacity rule. You can see an updated and working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/140/)

For an **entirely cross browser** solution see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PPpnT/13/)

Comment: You beauty! Thanks a heap :-)

Comment: I have just tried your examples in IE and chrome - chrome is fine however, IE will display the content underneath the image first onload and then will hide - also some of the examples in IE do not work - suggestions?

Comment: Try using 'filter'. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/PPpnT/11/ using filter: alpha(opacity = 0)

Comment: That works good for IE 8 but 7 is still showing what is underneath, is there a way around this?

Comment: Perfect - just needed to change the opacity! Thanks dude :-)

Answer (score 1):

I updated your jsfiddle. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/139/) is the link. My code uses jquery onmouseover function

Answer (score 0):

I think that in css

```css
a img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

should be enough.

Comment: Need cross browser support...filter:opacity(alpha=0);

Answer (score 0):

The opacity is not supported by all browsers, i think you should go the display way:

```
a img:hover {
    display: none;
}
```